# Use awk, or sed commands to remove the letters and parenthesis from the rows of a file

Tags: awk

I have an input file as below,

```
group_velocity: [     0.0000000      0.0000000      0.0000000 ]
group_velocity: [     6.8213667      5.2673206      0.0002496 ]
group_velocity: [    19.0751734     29.0686833      0.0006979 ]
```

Now, I want to use the awk/sed command, such that the output file would look as:

```
   0.0000000      0.0000000      0.0000000 
   6.8213667      5.2673206      0.0002496 
   19.0751734     29.0686833     0.0006979
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
echo "group_velocity: [     0.0000000      0.0000000      0.0000000 ]
group_velocity: [     6.8213667      5.2673206      0.0002496 ]
group_velocity: [    19.0751734     29.0686833      0.0006979 ]" | awk '{print $3, $4, $5}'
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks Cristian a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If data are in same format all time, this should do:

```
awk '{print $3,$4,$5}' file
0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
6.8213667 5.2673206 0.0002496
19.0751734 29.0686833 0.0006979
```

If formatting is important:

```
awk '{print $3,$4,$5}' OFS="\t" file
0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000
6.8213667       5.2673206       0.0002496
19.0751734      29.0686833      0.0006979
```

Comment: Thanks Jotne a lot, It worked perfectly except the comma was still present.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tr -dc '0-9. \n' < file
      0.0000000      0.0000000      0.0000000
      6.8213667      5.2673206      0.0002496
     19.0751734     29.0686833      0.0006979
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  's/^.*\[\|\].*//g' input_file
```

This is deleting everything from start till `[` and `]` till end.

Or using back referencing:

```
 sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g' input_file
```

This will extract the text between the two `[` and `]`.

Comment: @AbhiyanPandit if the answer helped you , please accept the answer by clicking on the right mark besides the answer. This is an acknowledgement that your question is answered and encourage members to respond to your questions .